# Maven command line arguments in IntelliJ 14.

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've been learning Maven and absolutely love it, it's an incredible tool.  I'm currently running mvn clean, build, compile, package etc from terminal.  This works fine but I figure I could do all this from the IDE.  However, using -clean as a command line arg in the configuration settings throws an error.

The current command is simply idea:idea.  When this runs it appears to be building the project and adding resources but no mention of clean / verify etc.

I've searched various jet brains pages but can't find a commandline list.  Ideally I'd like to be able to set up a couple of different configurations, these mimicking the cones that I'd call from the terminal.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In intellij you have [Maven Projects Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-projects-tool-window.html) which you can use to run any maven build phase or plugin goals, you can also create run configurations from them (just right click and select create).

You can also create maven run configurations by yourself using [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configurations.html) dialog. There should be maven type available on the list.

> However, using -clean as a command line arg in the configuration settings throws an error.

You should pass just `clean` as command line argument.
You can read more about how to call maven for example from [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)

Comment: feeling like a complete noob right now.  Thank you! :)

Comment: Also try [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce)